# Is there a way to add 2 groundchecks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Is there a way to add 2 ground check transforms that will work together? I have my original ground check on the front foot of the player as this improves the ability to help jump onto platforms if the player just catches the edge of it. However, I found that due to the position of this ground check, if the player does a last minute jump from one platform to the other, the ground check comes off of the current platform and now isGrounded = false and the player cannot jump. I am using:

isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, whatIsGround);

This statement allows for 5 overloads, but I am unsure how to go about it. I thought about simply adding this statement again to the code with a different ground check. However, if possible, I'd like to keep them together. I couldn't find any docs outlining how to do this or what adding an overload would look like.

Thanks in advance and enjoy the rest of your holidays!

Comment: Is there no way to stretch an transform to cover whole width of the feet? that would ensure that you catch edges in front, but not miss ones on the back.

Comment: @markovic-m I don't believe you can stretch a transform? I could be wrong. But I just used 2 transforms and added the OR operator in the statement as per the comment below. Thanks for chiming in though!

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is set `isGrounded` to true for either ground check, you should be able to run both `Linecasts` with an OR operator.

```
isGrounded = ((Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position,
                                  groundCheck.position, 
                                  whatIsGround) ||
              (Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, 
                                  groundCheck2.transform.position,
                                  whatIsGround));
```

Here's an example of how you could go about doing this.

Comment: omg I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you, it solved my problem!